# How to get tomcat running on Raspberry Pi with ArchLinux?

Tags: archlinux

I have a model B Raspberry Pi running ArchLinux.  I want to run tomcat on it but so far haven't found a package anywhere.  (There is a tomcat-natives package, but no tomcat6 or 7.)

Google search shows a few people have done it, but none explain where they got it or how to install.

Answer (score 3):

Find the solution [here](http://macgyverdev.blogspot.be/2012/08/raspberry-pi-how-to-get-ssh-and-tomcat.html)

- First u need to install java

  sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
- Then download and install tomcat

  wget http://mirrors.axint.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.28/bin/apache-tomcat-.0.28.tar.gz

  tar xzf apache-tomcat-7.0.28.tar.gz

  cd apache-tomcat-7.0.28/conf

  vim tomcat-users.xml

If the package can't be found don't forget to use

```
apt-get update
```

- Add a user to the authorization file

directly below "< tomcat-users>" add

```
< user username="system" password="raspberry" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

- And now run tomcat

  cd ../bin
  sudo sh startup.sh

Comment: he is running Arch. why are you guys give him the instruction on Ubuntu?

Comment: If your governance allows; I would *strongly* advise using the Oracle JDK with Tomcat, and not Open JDK.  With due respect to the Open JDK, I've observed that performance is better on Oracle JDK in general, and especially so with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

first you will need java

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre -y
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install wget -y

wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.37/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.37.tar.gz

tar -zvxf apache-tomcat-7.0.37.tar.gz

mv apache-tomcat-7.0.37 tomcat

cd tomcat/bin

./startup.sh
```

bingo.

Answer (score 0):

Installing and configuring tomcat from the tomcat site isnt much harder than installing a packaged version, and will be newer. Just read the docs, run the scripts, and dont forget to make a user in the XML file. P.S it may run slow. Last time I used Tomcat was v6 and it struggled on machines with not much RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Try with stock Tomcat first.

Packaged tomcat (e.g. on Debian) may have some file permissions problems. If your app creates database in default folder you need to check permissions before you start the app.

With stock Tomcat you don't have that problem as you may run everything from your folder.